# C# WPF PolyLine that is 50% of my window width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, polyline

this should be an easy answer for some of you maybe.
I wan to draw a line that is always 50% of my window width, how do i do that?
So if the user resizes the window, the line should be able to automatically adjust itself and grow/shrink to always keep 50% of my window width.

How to do that? Currently, i only have a very static line....such as....

```
<Polyline Points="0,0 1,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="500" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="10" />
```

where my window width is set to 1000.

Comment: Do you want a vertical line to have the thickness of half your window or keep its thickness but stay in the center? Or do you want a horizontal one with one end stuck to the side of the window and the other one to stay stuck in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the same effect with a `Path` control. The `Data` property value uses a pair of `Move` elements to define the nominal size of the drawing surface.

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" Data="M 100,0 M 0,0 L 50,0" Stretch="Uniform" />
```